# how to check if _variant_t is NULL

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am reading data from excel cell via ADO

```
while (!pRec->adoEOF)
{
    _variant_t a = pRec->Fields->GetItem(long(0))->Value;
    //todo
}
```

how to check if *`a`* equal `NULL`

```
a.bstrVal==NULL
```

it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
a.vt == VT_NULL // Represents a NULL received from a database
```

Or

```
a.vt == VT_EMPTY // Represents an uninitialized object
```

Database Nulls have a specific representation in `VARIANT`.

However if it is from Excel it's also possible you are getting an empty string rather than a null.

```
a.vt == VT_BSTR && SysStringLen(a.bstrVal) == 0
```